# Best way to monitor for a key press without stopping a loop

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing a program in C++ for Linux. I plan on using `popen()` to run another program. While I'm waiting for that program to finish, I want to be able to detect if the user presses keys on the keyboard so I know if they want to continue processing their files or if they want to pause after `pclose()`. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: as your pipe and your console are simple files, you can check if input is available by using `select` and do the needed actions. No need to create a new thread for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a thread waiting for a key before calling `popen`, call `popen`, cancel the thread and check if any key was pressed before calling `pclose`.

An example using C (it is trivial to adapt it to C++), I'm ommiting error checks for brevity:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *handler(void *arg)
{
    int *key = arg;
    char c;

    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1))
    {
        if (*key == 0)
        {
            *key = c;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int key = 0;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handler, &key);

    // Simulate a long read using sleep 5
    // to give you enough time to press a key + enter
    FILE *cmd = popen("sleep 5; echo 'command finished'", "r");
    char str[1024];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, cmd))
    {
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    pthread_cancel(thread);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    if (key != 0)
    {
        printf("%c was pressed\n", key);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Someone suggested in comments to use `select` instead of `pthread`s, I don't see much advantage in using `select` but here we go:

`select()` allows to wait until a file descriptor (in this case `stdin`) become ready, it can be connected to a timeout that specifies the interval that `select()` should block waiting for the file descriptor to become ready, in this case, since we want to `read` what is pending on `stdin` as soon as `popen` finishes, we set the timeout to 0, at the end we need to clean `stdin`, otherwise we end up poluting the terminal with garbage if the user starts typing but doesn't hit enter, or types more than one digit pressing enter.

IMHO threads are a cleaner alternative in this case. Same approach using `select`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>

void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int stdin_copy = dup(STDIN_FILENO);

    tcdrain(stdin_copy);
    tcflush(stdin_copy, TCIFLUSH);
    close(stdin_copy);
}

int keypress(int state)
{
    int key = 0;

    // state 0 = timeout (nothing to get)
    if (state == 1)
    {
        char c;

        if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1))
        {
            key = c;
        }
    }
    clear_stdin();
    return key;
}

int main(void)
{
    fd_set set;

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &set);

    FILE *cmd = popen("sleep 5; echo 'command finished'", "r");
    char str[1024];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, cmd))
    {
        printf("%s", str);
    }

    struct timeval timeout;

    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int state = select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    int key = keypress(state);

    if (key != 0)
    {
        printf("%c was pressed\n", key);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not sure I understand what is going on. Could you provide some more information on what is happening?

Comment: Yes of course, there are two threads running in paralell, the thread that was create in`pthread_create` and the process itself (the main process). When you call `pthread_create` the function handler starts waiting for a key while the main process do his job calling popen, when popen finishes the main process cancels and stop  the thread that was waiting for a key, you need a join to wait the thread to cleanup his stuff, at this moment you can ask for the value of the shared variable `key`, thats all :). Sorry for my bad english.